# Have a left join where duplicates in the second table is involved - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Table 1:

```
user  score  
------------
A      1    
B      2
```

Table 2:

```
    user   comment    time
    ----------------------------
    A      good     <timestamp 1>
    A      bad      <timestamp 2>
    B      average  <timestamp 3>
```

I want to join these two tables such that I get the below:

```
    user   score  comment
    -------------------------
    A      1        good
    B      2       average
```

As you can see I'll need to join the second table's comment based on the timestamp (the most recent timestamp). I tried

```
SELECT st.user as user,st.score,
case when v.comment is null then 'NA' else v.comment end as comment
FROM tale1
left JOIN (select distinct user,comment,max(time) from table2) v ON st.user=v.user
```

but this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join with a correlated subquery that filters on the latest timestamp:

```
select 
    t1.*,
    t2.comment
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
    on t2.user = t1.user
    and t2.time = (
        select max(t22.time)
        from table2 t22
        where t21.user = t1.user
    )
```

Side note: I am unsure that you do need a `left join` here (your sample data does not demonstrate that).

Comment: Yes. This makes sense more than a left join. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You only want one column from `table2` so I recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.comment
        from table2 t2
        where t2.user = t1.user
        order by t2.time desc
        limit 1
       ) as comment
from table1 t1;
```

This query will make optimal use of an index on `table2(user, time desc, comment)` -- alas, though, I think the `desc` is ignored in MySQL.